# How to get to a new ArrayList data?

Tags: java, arraylist

i made a class "Time" with some variables like: "int year,month,days" .
Now, i added data to ArrayList  like:

```
ArrayList<Time> list = new ArrayList<Time>();
list.add(new Time(2014,15,3));
list.add(new Time(2013,1,5));
list.add(new Time(2011,15,3));
list.add(new Time(2014,12,4));
```

now for filtering the data by year and month i create a for loop like:

```
for(i = 0; i<=list.size();i++)
{
    if(list.get(i).getYear == 2014 && list.get(i).getMonth == 12)
    {
        templist.add(new Time(list.get(i).getYear(),list.get(i).getMonth(),list.get(i).getDay()));
    }
}
```

and then it's filtered.. but i think is a very bad practice because my Time.class has alot of variables beside the dates and i want to pass all of them together ,i'm know how to use" Collection.sort " and "Comparator" but i'm sure there is a better way to do it .. like addAll or something.. what do you think?

Comment: How can this for loop sort the data?

Comment: What better way of sorting a list other than `Collections.sort` would you think of? Yes there are other ways, maybe even slightly faster ones (depends on the data), but do you _really_ need to bother?

Comment: this for loop has a condition and if the conditions are "true" i'ts added the data with the current position (i) to a temp ArrayList

Comment: I am very weak in Collections.sort.. but if you recommend I would be very Grateful if you give me an example how to do it in my case..

Comment: Use Time.clone() to preserve all variables

Comment: Show us what is your sorting logic currently

Comment: Since `Time` does have a natural ordering IMHO, I'd go with implementing `Comparable`. Btw, why aren't you using  `Date` etc., e.g. the time based classes already provided by Java?

Comment: @kai apparently OP mistakenly tought of sorting as filtering... that's why the loop can sort (filter) the data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to filter collections of course, using lambda (fitur available on Java 8).

```
List<Time> times = new ArrayList<Time>
List<Time> filteredTimes = times.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getYear() == 2014 && t.getMonth() == 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

See more about that [here](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/).

---

Apparently OP mistakenly tought filter as sorting. This is outdated answer for sorting answer

No, using `Comparator` is not a bad pactice and it's the correct way in Java to do custom sorting. You hate it because it's so verbose? Welcome to the world of Java.

Either create a new `Comparator` class (you can use static definition inside of `Time`) and uses `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` to sort it, or make `Time` class implements `Comparable`, and just uses `Collections.sort(List<T> list)`

If you are looking a list that always sorted whenever you insert new item, then you are looking for [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). But it's a queue, so you can't get item at random index except the head. But, you still need the Comparable / Comparator to make the queue able to sort it.

For your case, assume you wanted to sort the `Time` class by year first, month second, and then date third. You create a Comparator object:

```
class TimeSorterByYearMonthDate implements Comparator<Time>{
    int compare(Time o1,Time o2) {
         if (o1.getYear() != o2.getYear() ) return o1.getYear().compareTo(o2.getYear());
         if (o1.getMonth() != o2.getMonth() ) return o1.getMonth().compareTo(o2.getMonth());
         return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
    }
}
```

And then sort it with `Collections.sort(yourList, new TimeSorterByYearMonthDate());`

Comment: Thank you but i want to sort it by years and month not by sort order

Comment: When you call `Collections.sort` it'll sort all the object inside the list with least year first, and then least month, and then least date. Is that not what you want?

Comment: no . i just want to get only the year 2014 and the month april for example, and add them to new arrayList. I know use Collections.sort

Comment: That's not sorting!! That's filtering! You're confusing everyone reading your question.

Comment: But with the Collections.sort i can filtering?

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: t cannot be resolved ? why that? and the "->" give me error too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60519/discussion-between-dieend-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) is the best way to do it.
Here is how you can do it using a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Time>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Time t1, final Time t2) {
        if (t1.getYear() != t2.getYear())
            return t1.getYear() - t2.getYear();
        if (t1.getMonth() != t2.getMonth())
            return t1.getMonth() - t2.getMonth();
        return t1.getDay() - t2.getDay();
    }
});

for (final Time time : list) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", time.getYear(), time.getDay(), time.getMonth());
}
```

---

And here is how to do it implementing the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface:

First, you `Time` class:

```
public class Time implements Comparable<Time> {
    int year;
    int day;
    int month;

    //...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Time t) {
        if (this.getYear() != t.getYear())
            return this.getYear() - t.getYear();
        if (this.getMonth() != t.getMonth())
            return this.getMonth() - t.getMonth();
        return this.getDay() - t.getDay();
    }
}
```

Then, you can sort your list using:

```
Collections.sort(list);

for (final Time time : list) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", time.getYear(), time.getDay(), time.getMonth());
}
```

---

Alternatively, once `Time`implements `Comparable`, you can use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead of an `ArrayList`, in order to sort your `Time`s as they are added to the set:

```
TreeSet<Time> set = new TreeSet<Time>();
set.add(new Time(2014, 15, 3));
set.add(new Time(2013, 1, 5));
set.add(new Time(2011, 15, 3));
set.add(new Time(2014, 12, 4));

for (final Time time : set) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", time.getYear(), time.getDay(), time.getMonth());
}
```

Comment: Sir it would have been better if you just gave the OP the guidelines,not ready to use code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Collections.sort`. you just need to `Override` the `compareTo` function in your `Time` class and `implements Comparable`. here is the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of Comparable

Answer (score 0):

"**but i'm sure there is a better way to do it ..**"

**NO**, you should use the `Comparator`, or let your `Time` class implement `Comparable`. Using `Collections.sort()` is the  standard technique to sort data structures in Java.